# multithreading in c - WINAPI

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to make a simple program that creates 4 threads and each one of them has to loop for 1000 times and each time print its thread number (1 to 4) and its position in the loop.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work at all (prints weird stuff); I would be glad if someone will help me to find my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI threadFunc(LPVOID lparam)
{
    INT num = *(PINT)lparam;
    for (INT i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        printf("Thread %d, var = %d\n", num, i);
    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    INT num1 = 1;
    INT num2 = 2;
    INT num3 = 3;
    INT num4 = 4;

    HANDLE h[4];
    h[0] = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        threadFunc,
        &num1,
        0,
        NULL);
    h[1] = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        threadFunc,
        &num2,
        0,
        NULL);
    h[2] = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        threadFunc,
        &num3,
        0,
        NULL);
    h[3] = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        threadFunc,
        &num4,
        0,
        NULL);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(
        4,
        h,
        TRUE,
        INFINITY);
    
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about which language you are using: You state C (and had the C tag) but use the `<iostream>` header, which is C++. Can you please clarify? (I'll happily revert my tag-edit.)

Comment: This is Win32 API in C (maybe your compiler says it is C++ but you are using pure C). `<iostream>` is not necessary and `WinMain()` must be used instead of `main`.

Comment: @i486 Actually, the code *can* be built as a console-mode application, which **does** use `main` (not `WinMain`). But, as C code, the `#include <stdio.h>` is still needed, as `windows.h` doesn't define `printf`.

Comment: @AdrianMole technically, if that MS compiler, it's C++ one. Microsoft doesn't have C compiler and their compiler isn't C99 (or later) compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incorrect value for the last argument in your `WaitForMultipleObjects` call! The constant `INFINITY` (defined by `math.h`, or one of its 'children', as `((float)(_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF))`) is a **floating-point** constant used for detection of overflow-related stuff.

What you ***should*** use, instead, is the `INFINITE` constant (defined in `WinBase.h` as `0xFFFFFFFF`). *(What a difference one letter can make!)*

With full compiler warnings enabled, you would spot this! MSVC, for *your* code, gives:

> warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'DWORD',
> possible loss of data

With the aforementioned change, your code runs as expected when I test it with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 (64-bit).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The code has a race on the call to print, so it doesn't really work

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are, unsurprisingly, correct. When I said, "runs as expected," I (implicitly) included the possibility of garbled output.